# Power Platform Dataflow Access Timeout

Tags: mfa, dataflow

I'm working inside of Power Platform. I need to connect a dataflow using Power Query to a specific object and report for a client. The connection is fine but the Salesforce account has MFA turned on and disconnects the dataflow after a certain period of time. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

It's best if you use the new [Integration User license type](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.integration_user.htm&type=5) for integration connections.  You get 5 licenses for free!

However, beware that the profile has no object permissions by default, so you'll need to build a permission set for it.